# lastInsertId not returning value after first record. How do I go about checking for this?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

I have the following PHP script which runs nicely and inserts all the data into MySQL using the PDO transaction correctly, but only on the first run through. After the initial run through, I try inserting the same data again. The first `lastInsertId` then starts to return 0 because the `unique key` attribute on the `email` field is stopping a new `userId`value being created via `auto_increment`.

After reading through similar answers I'm still stuck as to how to check for this situation and fix the problem. I wrote the `$userCheck` so that I could see if the value from `$fromParsed` matched that of an email address already in the database. I don't know how to take the value of this query and then edit the script so that if a user is already in there with the same email address then it gets the `userId` of `$fromParsed`, and if `$fromParsed` isn't already in there, insert it then continue using `lastInsertId();` to get the `userId`.

I did try searching for an answer to this but I couldn't find anything that gave me a clear answer for a similar situation involving PDO transactions.

Sorry if the answer to this is blindly obvious.

```
try {

    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', 'password');

    $attachmentsQuery = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO attachments SET attachmentName = :attachmentName, content = :content, fileType = :fileType');
    $usersQuery = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO users SET email = :email');
    $emailsQuery = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO emails SET userId = :userId, subject = :subject, body = :body, attachmentId = :attachmentId');
    $userCheck = $con->prepare("SELECT userId FROM users WHERE email = '$fromParsed'");

    try {
        $con->beginTransaction();

        $userCheck->execute();
        //Something here?

        $usersQuery->bindParam(':email', $fromParsed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $usersQuery->execute();

        $userId = $con->lastInsertId();

        $attachmentsQuery->bindParam(':attachmentName', $filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $attachmentsQuery->bindParam(':fileType', $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $attachmentsQuery->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $attachmentsQuery->execute();

        $attachmentId = $con->lastInsertId();

        $emailsQuery->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $emailsQuery->bindParam(':attachmentId', $attachmentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $emailsQuery->bindParam(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $emailsQuery->bindParam(':body', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $emailsQuery->execute();

        $con->commit();

        } catch(Exception $e) {
                $dbo->rollback();
                die();
        }
} catch(Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I understand nesting a `try/catch` inside a `catch`, but why would you nest it inside a `try` if you're not going to conditionally re `throw`? Move the bottom `catch` block above the inner `try`, it will separate your code more sensibly, one block which sets up the connection and prepares the queries, another block which executes them. Along the same lines, maybe you could fix your problem by doing `if (!$userId) throw new Exception("User exists");`?

Comment: Are you doing this operat,on in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
if($userCheck->execute() && $userCheck->rowCount() > 0){
    // we have a user.
    $data = $userCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $userId = $data['userId'];
}
else {

    $usersQuery->bindParam(':email', $fromParsed, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $usersQuery->execute();

    $userId = $con->lastInsertId();
}
//Something here?
```

Brief explanation, this will place the results from the $userQuery into $data if there is a record dictated by the rowCount.  If the query returns no results, it will continue to execute your $userQuery and return a userId for the newly created entry.

Comment: You Damon, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you for this - it worked perfectly.